# Website development and testing in Eclipse and Tomcat: javascript is cached

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, tomcat

I'm developing a web application with jsp pages in Eclipse 3.7.2 and testing it with Tomcat v6.0.

I've almost the perfect environment as all changes to my jsp or java code are immediately available in the browser within Eclipse, so I can directly test any change.

But... I also use jQuery, who isn't ;-), and changes in my javascript files are not immediately active. Looks like they are cached or copied once and don't get replaced. Even after rebuilding or restarting the tomcat, the old files keep being used.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks a lot,
Frank

Comment: clear your browser cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [**firebug**](http://getfirebug.com/) in your browser, you can switch off the caching by default without adding code to your page:

click the arrow on the right side of the **Networking** button and select the **disable browser cache** option.

Comment: apparantly restarting tomcat and disabling browser cache solves the problem when testing the web app in a seperate browser. The problem only remains in the browser withing eclipse. Think I will have to use the external browser...

Comment: using an external browser is generally advisable as you should test your application on browsers you expect your users to use. The percentage of visits from the embedded eclipse brower tend to be rather small ;)

Answer (score 1):

The files are probably cached by the browser.

ctrl-F5 might help but if you can configure the server to set no cache for js and css that should also help.

Another solution is to load all such files through a loader,

```
/load.<site extension, ex php>?file=myscript.js
```

And have that "proxy" set no cache.

We use that along with e-tag to be able to use build number as e-tag, vith every build a new version is forced to clients but then cached until next build.